# How to search in contained resources?

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I'm looking into FHIR and stumbling over the search query for resources containing resources. I'm using the HAPI JPA Examples server and have some DiagnosticReports stored there. Some of them containing a Organization with a certain name. I really can't figure out how to query this. I tried to follow the HL7 FHIR Search docs, but it isn't working.

http://example.com/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-example/baseDstu2/DiagnosticReport?organization.name=XYZ

The server's answer:

Invalid request: The FHIR endpoint on this server does not know how to handle GET operation[DiagnosticReport] with parameters [[organization.name]]

What am I doing wring? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks valid from the spec point of view. I've asked the HAPI team to look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point HAPI's JPA module does not allow you to search with matches in contained resources. FHIR does have a query format to allow this, but we haven't implemented it yet.

However, that's not even the issue here: DiagnosticReport does not have a search parameter called "organization", since there is no field called "organization" on the DR resource. Presumably you're after something like `DiagnosticReport?patient.organization.name=XYZ` or `DiagnosticReport.performer.name=XYZ`